# Get more than one string as a variable into input separated by space

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.

I need to get three values from a input (separated by a space). The values are a integer, a string and a integer again.
Consider that the string can have more than one word. 
If I set two words it does not work, because each word is like a value.
My code into the momment is:

```
list_a = {}
list_b = []
for i in range(4):
    input_values = input("Press {}, {} and {}".format("id1", "name", "id2"))
    id1, name, id2 = input_values.split()

    list_a["id1"] = id1
    list_a["name"] = name
    list_a["id2"] = id2

    list_b.append(dict(list_a))

print(list_b)
```

If my input is something like 1 name_ok 0, it works. But if my input is something like 1 pasta ok 0, doesn't works because 3 values are expected, not 4.

How could I do to consider that any character between the two integer values ​​was the variable name?

Sorry about the english xD

Comment: Split the first, then split the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily know that `id2` is the *third* argument; it's the *last* argument. You can gather all the intervening arguments into a single tuple using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). Once you have the tuple of middle arguments, you can join them back together.

```
id1, *names, id2 = input_valores.split()

list_a["id1"] = int(id1)
list_a["name"] = " ".join(names)
list_a["id2"] = int(id2)
```

This is somewhat lossy, as it contracts arbitrary whitespace in the name down to a single space; you get the same result of `1`, `"foo bar"`, and `2` from `"1 foo bar 2"` and `"1 foo     bar 2"`, for instance. If that matters, you can use split twice:

```
# This is the technique alluded to in  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' comment.
id1, rest = input_valores.split(None, 1)
name, id2 = rest.rsplit(None, 1)
```

`rsplit` is like `split`, but starts at the other end. In both cases, the `None` argument specifies the default splitting behavior (arbitrary whitespace), and the argument `1` limits the result to a single split. As a result, on the first and last space is used for splitting; the intermediate spaces are preserved.

Comment: Worth noting that the `*` syntax does not work with Python 2.7 (still a good answer though because OP mentioned they are working with Python 3)

Comment: Indeed; I started with a slice-based answer before I noticed the `python-3.x` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing.

```
args = input('Enter ID, name, and second ID').split()
id1 = int(args[0])
id2 = int(args[-1])
name = " ".join(args[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use python's slicing notation for this

```
input_values = input("Press {}, o {} e o {}".format("id1", "name", "id2"))
listSplit = input_values.split()

id1 = listSplit[0]
name = join(listSplit[1:-1])
id2 = listSplit[-1]

def join(arr):
newStr = ""
for i in arr:
    newStr += i + " "
return newStr[:-1]
```

where id1 is the first word, name is everything between the first index and the last which has been joined into one string and the *third* argument which is actually the last word.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You don't have to define `join`; it's already defined as a `str` method. `name = " ".join(listSplit[1:-1])`.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
split = input_values.split()
id1 = int(split[0])
id2 = int(split[-1])
name = " ".join(split[1:-1])
```